# IOS: question about change view in weather app (in iPhone)

Tags: ios, view, uiscrollview

I want to know how to scroll two or more view as in weather app (in iPhone basilar app).
If you know weather app, you know that you can add a location. When you add two location, you can scroll through these location. You can scroll also with a "n" number of location.
In my application I want to replicate the same thing.
Do you know the code? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `UIScrollView` (each weather location is a `UIView` added to the `UIScrollView`). The `UIScrollView` has "paging" turned on. At the bottom the dots is a `UIPageControl` that allows control of the `UIScrollView`.

Googling UIScrollView will bring up a multitude of tutorials.

http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html

Are a couple good ones.